# How to logout from Oauth signed in web app with GitHub?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, backend

I have implemented OAuth using GitHub on my web app, so when I log in using GitHub I get logged in successfully. I wanted to know how to implement logout so that I get logged out of the web app.

when the user visits www.localhost:3000/login and clicks login/signup with GitHub, the user gets redirected to the GitHub login page, user logs in with his/her GitHub account and gets redirected to localhost:3000/homepage,
I sent a cookie from the server side for session purposes and get a cookie from GitHub (don't know why).

[image: cookie set in my browser after login with github]

when I clear cookies from localhost:3000 and visit localhost:3000/login and hit login with the GitHub button I get logged in with the previously signed-in user account automatically. However, when I clear all cookies from [www.github.com](http://www.github.com) and do the same, this time it prompts the user to log in with the git account again.

I have not used any external library like passport.js for OAuth and also I don't want to use any.

so how to implement this logout that logs out of the GitHub OAuth session?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is "single log-out" whereby logging out from your application also logs out from GitHub. But the relevant [specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html) has been finalized only in September 2022 and I could not find any mention of it at docs.github.com. Perhaps this is also not desired, since GitHub sessions are long-lasting: Revisiting github.com with the same browser after a few days does not require a re-logon.

But as an alternative to logging out from GitHub upon *logout* from your application, you could require a renewed consent upon *re-login* to your application. If you have already been logged in once to your application via GitHub and then visit

```
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=user:email&client_id=...
```

you are re-logged in silently. But if you visit

```
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=user:email&client_id=...&prompt=consent
```

instead, the GitHub consent screen re-appears. (The parameter `prompt=consent` is not documented on docs.github.com, but is explained [here](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest).)

Perhaps that is sufficient to satisfy your requirement.